# Scalate Jade multiple includes doesn't work as expected

Tags: pug, scalate

Partial 1, widget1.jade:

```
p 1
```

Partial 2, widget2.jade:

```
p 2
```

Layout attempt 1:

```
- include("widget1.jade")
```

This renders:

```
<p>1</p>
```

Layout attempt 2:

```
- include("widget2.jade")
```

This renders:

```
<p>2</p>
```

Layout attempt 3:

```
- include("widget1.jade")

- include("widget2.jade")
```

Renders:

```
<p>1</p>
<p>1</p>
```

Can anybody validate this? Bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of scalate/OS/configuration you are using?

On OS X, with Scalate 1.5.3 i've got the following:

```
mcbatyuk:scalate bam$ cat view1.jade 
p 1


mcbatyuk:scalate bam$ cat view2.jade
p 2

mcbatyuk:scalate bam$ cat compound.jade 
- include("view1.jade")

- include("view2.jade")
```

Now running the compound template:

```
scalate> run compound.jade 
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
```

I'm concerned with the fact that running from the command line $ scalate run compound.jade doesn't actually do anything, but that's another story :-)